# SonarQube Force Authentication with Anonymous scan upload

Tags: java, maven, authentication, sonarqube, sonarscanner

tl:dr; We would like to enable Force Authentication while still allowing anonymous scans/uploads to sonarqube.

Sonarqube v.6.7.5

We have a requirement of enforcing authentication into the sonarqube UI. To enable this, we have configured LDAP and the “Force Authentication” option.

This has worked as desired from the UI’s perspective as we wish to limit who can view the projects/scans on sonarqube. However, we would still like anyone (anonymous users) to submit their projects for scanning analysis (they will just have to login to actually see the results).

Upon enabling Force Authentication, our previously working maven command fails with the following error (below). I am aware of using the *sonar.login* and *sonar.password* arguments, but we would like to avoid that, and allow anonymous users. Mainly we would like to avoid people having to send in their credentials or tokens and just use a simpler command.

Is it possible to have both Forced Authentication while still allowing anonymous uploads to sonarqube? Any help would be greatly appear, thank you

Regards,
Erik

**mvn command**:

```
mvn -X -Dsonar.clover.reportPath=target/site/clover/clover.xml -Dsonar.host.url=${sonarqube_url} org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar
```

**maven output***:

```
[DEBUG] 14:20:22.416 GET 401 ${sonarqube_url}/sonar/api/settings/values.protobuf | time=215ms
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.404 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-06-27T14:20:22-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/194M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project cyberark-poc: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.ScannerPluginInstaller: Unable to load component class org.sonar.home.cache.FileCache: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalConfiguration: Not authorized. Analyzing this project requires to be authenticated. Please provide the values of the properties sonar.login and sonar.password. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project cyberark-poc: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.ScannerPluginInstaller
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.ScannerPluginInstaller
at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:36)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:81)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:122)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
… 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.ScannerPluginInstaller
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:64)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.instantiateComponentAsIsStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1034)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.addAdapterIfStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1026)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1003)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:134)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doStart(Batch.java:94)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.start(Batch.java:88)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.start(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:52)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.start(Unknown Source)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStart(EmbeddedScanner.java:220)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.start(EmbeddedScanner.java:156)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:60)
… 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.home.cache.FileCache
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:64)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:62)
… 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalConfiguration
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:64)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getMemberArguments(SingleMemberInjector.java:61)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.getMemberArguments(MethodInjector.java:100)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector$2.run(MethodInjector.java:112)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.decorateComponentInstance(MethodInjector.java:120)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.CompositeInjector.decorateComponentInstance(CompositeInjector.java:58)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.Reinjector.reinject(Reinjector.java:142)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ProviderAdapter.getComponentInstance(ProviderAdapter.java:96)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:62)
… 65 more
Caused by: Not authorized. Analyzing this project requires to be authenticated. Please provide the values of the properties sonar.login and sonar.password.
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to have both Forced Authentication while still allowing anonymous uploads to sonarqube?

No. You cannot force people to login and at the same time allow using the server without login (SonarScanner pushes results to the server by Web API services which are served by the same server which serves Web UI).

Comment: Hey @agabrys, thanks for responding. As a follow up, do you know if it's possible (or a way) to configure a type of _default_ token that we can somehow apply to all scan commands? Essentially, if people provide their own tokens, use that, however, if they don't provide anything, use a default token? Possibly via group configuration?

Comment: Two ideas (both ugly). 1) create your own scanner, which proxies the original scanner and add the default token if users didn't specify it. 2) configure a proxy server which will add the default token to request when it is missing.

Comment: Thanks again @agabrys. I think we will look at using permission templates. Possibly leave force authentication off, but make every project private. Then use groups to manage who can see what. A bit more administrative work, but a must to meet our requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Accepting @agabrys' response as it answers the question, however posting our workaround for others who may be interested.

We will be disabling Force Authentication, and will be using [Permission Templates](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/security/), along with making projects private. This will prevent anonymous access to the analysis results and source code from the UI, however still allow anyone (anonymous) to submit code for analyzation.